# How to extract single side of signal spectrum in SIMULINK

Tags: matlab, complex

Signal spectrum have two side, positive and negative. I want to make these separate in two signal, by MATALB SIMULINK.
But how? I can't find it's block on DSP or communication toolbox.
I found a block that interactively generate filter, but this filters response is conjugate symmetric and that's not my desire.
As replica of Fat32 :
Hilbert approach not worked?!!
[image: Hilbert approach]

Comment: what you're looking for sounds like the *analytic signal*; maybe that's a term that helps you find a good solution?

Comment: I'm thinking yes, it's easiest answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a single side band separation block-diagram in Simulink, then you would try the following algorithm to separate the upper sideband from the lower sideband given that you have a block called **Hilbert** transformer.

Given that your original real valued baseband input signal is $x[n]$, then the following signal is called as the **analytic** signal:

$$  x^+[n] = x[n] + j \hat{x}[n] $$ where $$\hat{x}[n] = \mathcal{H} \{x[n] \} = \frac{1}{\pi n} \star x[n]$$ is called as the **Hilbert** transform of the signal $x[n]$.

It can be shown that the Fourier spectrum of the analytic signal is:
$$ X^+(\omega) = \begin{cases} 
2 X(\omega) &, \text{for } ~~~  0 < \omega < \pi \\ 
0 &, \text{for } ~~~ -\pi < \omega < 0\\ \end{cases}
$$

Which is 2x the upper side band of the signal $x[n]$

Comment: It seems right but why this is not working? I have used your approach but it not worked, I attached it picture to my question.

Comment: Matlab Hilbert function returns the **analytic signal** $x^+$ instead of the sole Hilbert transform of the signal $\hat{x}$ so you don't have to add $x$ to it. Look at your **documentation** to see if Siulink Hilbert block also does the same ?

Comment: No, it's simply Hilbert transform and I'm shocked since its output isn't complex.

Comment: There's nothing to shock. The output of a (theoretical) Hilbert transform is real (given the input is real). What's complex is the **analytic signal**. Matlab function y=hilbert(x) however returns the complex analytic signal $x^+ = x + j \hat{x} $ instead

Comment: `Hilbert`'s command working differently since it told on it's document: **Discrete-time analytic signal using Hilbert transform**

Comment: But I must not expect Hilbert output be complex since it convolved with 1/pi*t and it will be real. but why it's still not working???

Comment: Matlab function hilbert(x) returns the analytic signal $x^+[n] = x[n] + j*\hat{x}[n]$ which contains the upper side band of the baseband spectrum of $x[n]$. You can use it directly to achieve what you intend.

Comment: thanks for helping insistent. but time have been passed away and I'm not remember exactly, but I think I implemented the formula in Simulink, x+jx(hat). by only one Hilbert transform and delay block equal (N-1)/2.